# Tomcat 8.0.20 Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, tomcat, cloud-foundry

While deploying an application to Cloud Foundry using the [Cloud Foundry Java Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack) I started receiving an Out Of Memory error during application startup when the default Tomcat version changed from 2.0.18 to 2.0.20. Explicitly specifying 8.0.18 fixed the problem. This is using the Oracle 1.8 JRE.

Anyone else seeing this issue? Any ideas how to address/debug it?

The application did start in a standalone Tomcat 8.0.20 instance running under CentOS 6.6 (Final).

**EDIT**

It looks like the application was on the memory threshold using Tomcat 8.0.18. The original memory limit was set at 512M. Increasing that to 640M allowed the application to start. Which leads me to believe Tomcat 8.0.20 requires slightly more memory than 8.0.18.

For what it's worth, here's some more detail on the issue. This is using an offline buildpack. The Tomcat version is specified in the config/tomcat.yml. I changed the version specification from 8.+ to 8.0.18.

Original

```
tomcat:
  version: 8.+
  repository_root: "{default.repository.root}/tomcat"
```

Modified

```
tomcat:
  version: 8.0.18
  repository_root: "{default.repository.root}/tomcat"
```

Here's the specific error when using 8.0.20 with a memory limit of 512M:

App instance exited with guid 01832553-beba-49c3-8309-00f496c0b9ca payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"01832553-beba-49c3-8309-00f496c0b9ca", "version"=>"53af085e-9c38-49ff-afb0-c4702224b5ff", "instance"=>"44343b45b4ca48f19746e567a1ac9a45", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"out of memory", "crash_timestamp"=>1427824311}

Comment: Can you post a little more info?  This is kinda hard to debug this without anymore info...

Comment: I up voted your comment because it spurred me to include much needed detail. Thanks for your interest in the question.

Comment: That error message you posted shows virtually no useful information. Where did it come from? Neither Tomcat nor the JVM will report errors in JSON format. Do you have access to the Tomcat stdout log? For most installations, it's called `catalina.out` but there are many ways for it to be given another name or redirected elsewhere.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz The error came from the Java buildpack used in Cloud Foundry. So I didn't have access to catalina.out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message...

> "exit_description"=>"out of memory",

means that your application exceeded the memory limit that you set for it.  CF is very brutal enforcing the memory limit and exceeding it be even the smallest amount will result in your app being killed.

The Java build pack does it's best to configure the JVM so that it does not exceed the memory limit that you put in place, but unfortunately there is no way to guarantee that the JVM will never exceed the memory limit.  This is because while you can cap heap and metaspace usage, you can't cap things like thread stack and native memory usage.

There's more discussion of this on a KB article that I wrote [here](http://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/80755985-How-do-I-size-my-Java-or-JVM-based-applications-).  The document is focused towards Pivotal's hosted CF environment, but should generally apply to any CF environment.

As far as solutions, the easiest one is what you mentioned, which is to just increase the memory limit until things stabilize.

An alternative solution is to override the Java build packs memory configuration.  Specifically you could lower the thread stack size, which will lower the memory overhead of each thread and possibly keep you under the memory limit, or you can lower the heap and / or metaspace size (or percentage), which will leave more memory for other things and again hopefully keep you under the memory limit.

As a side note, adjusting the memory configuration set by the Java build pack used to require that you fork the build pack, however in a recent [commit](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/commit/bbb17a1b41cd961a9bae34958132aa4997154ad7) this has changed.  If you're using a recent version of the build pack, you can use the instructions [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/#configuration-and-extension) to change the memory configuration.

More about how the Java build pack configures the JVM can be found [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/jre-open_jdk_jre.md#configuration).

Comment: does this address the issue of 8.0.18 -> 8.0.20 version change causing memory issues in any way?

Comment: I accepted this as an answer because it points out ways to control the memory footprint. I think the root of the issue has to do with Tomcat 8.0.20 requires slightly more memory than 8.0.18. When I bumped the memory from 512M to 640M it worked.